# Is there a way or a python program or script to automatically install a set of EXEs that i have?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to install a set of applications (EXEs) on my PC and I need to know what time every application takes to finish installation. I'm doing this manually now, is there any way to automate this process ie.to install all applications and to display how much time every application took to get installed? Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `glob`, `os` and `time` packages.

```
python3
>>> help(glob)
```

The script you need is probably something like that :

```
import os,glob
from time import time
os.chdir("C:/tmp")
for files in glob.glob("*.exe"):
     t = time()
     os.system(files)
     print(time()-t)
```

Comment: so we have to give the directory which has the exes then it will install all the packages and give us the timings?

Comment: in the example that directory would be `c:\tmp`